# Upgrade Lync 2010 to Skype for Business Clients

Tags: lync, lync-2013, skype-for-business-2016, lync-2010

We currently have a Lync 2010 deployment, and are migrating to Skype for Business 2015.

From my reading, there is no way you can upgrade the clients direct from Lync 2010 to Skype for Business 2015/2016, and have to upgrade to Lync 2013 first, then apply the windows updates to update to S4B.

Looking for anyone who has some experience in this process, and essentially the best way to handle this transition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to go straight to S4B.

The best solution I found was to just install Office 2016, which would also install S4B 2016 Client. The Office 2016 installation. With [OCT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179097.aspx) you can customise the installation.